# Not getting the value from a div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to calculate amount without VAT  from a pre-calculated amount with VAT . The HTML form looks like :

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Sl No</th>
            <th>Description of goods</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>VAT%</th>
            <th>Price with VAT</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>   

    {foreach name = feach item = k from = $ip key = ind}
        <tr>
            <td>{$ind+1}</td>
            <td>{$k->brand},{$k->model}</td>
            <td id="prd_prc">&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="vat{$ind}">
                <select name="vatpc" id="vatpc" onchange="calculate('{$ind}')">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="13.5">13.5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="total_cost{$ind}">{$k->price}</td>
            <td>{$k->quantity}</td>
            <td>{$k->total_cost}</td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Total Cost </td>
            <td>{$final_amount}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And the JavaScript function is :

```
function calculate(idno)
{
    //alert(idno);
    var vat_pc = document.getElementById("vatpc").value;


    var total_cost = document.getElementById("total_cost"+idno).value;

    //total_cost = Number(total_cost);
    alert(total_cost);

    //vat_pc = parseFloat(vat_pc);
    // = v + 2.10 + 11.25;
    //alert(v);
    // document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total - amount : "+v+" USD";
}
```

But the alert shows `undefined`. I tried adding `innerHTML`,but results same. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: try to find out the value for `idno` , it is not coming mostly ...

Answer (score 2):

total_costX is a `<td>` element. Use the textContent property.

```
var total_cost = document.getElementById("total_cost"+idno).textContent;
```

Comment: Ya...I put the lines exactly according to you . Still its a NaN !

Comment: remove the parseFloat and see what is alerted.

Comment: Ya..the value within the id `<td id="total_cost{$ind}">`

Answer (score 0):

There in nothing like value of dive. But you can get text or html inside dive. if you are using jquery, it should be quite simple:

```
$(document.getElementById("vatpc")).text();
//OR
$(document.getElementById("vatpc")).html();
```

Or jQuery's way

$("#vatpc").text();
   //OR
   $("#vatpc").html();